# Why does sonar think annotating non-public methods with @Transactional is wrong?

Tags: sonarqube

We use aspect4J and compile time weaving.  Its perfectly valid to annotate private methods with @Transactional, or at least that is what I thought.  I am curious as to why sonar has the following rule:

Non-public methods should not be "@Transactional"

My guess is that sonar must be unaware that there are multiple ways to weave aspects and that the Spring default of using dynamic proxies is not the only way.

Its also interesting to note that this is of severity "critical".

Two questions:
1 - Is sonar wrong to assume that annotating a private method with @Transactional is wrong?
2 - If they are wrong how do I file a bug with the sonar team?

Answer (score 0):

We have also faced with a "@Transactional" issue in interfaces that appears to be a false positive:

- http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-967

Upgrading java plugin to latest version (3.3) fixed the issue.

As about non-public methods of the class, there is specification ticket in "Active" state:

- http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-2230

Answering your second question, I guess, their jira (http://jira.sonarsource.com) is the main bug-tracking system of the project.

Comment: I don't think either of these address my concern.  My main point here is that Sonar assumes the default spring behavior and dynamic proxy implementation.  Its a bad assumption.  There is no way to know what the runtime behvavior will be in regards to how aspects are injected.

Comment: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-2230 is in fact a continuation of this invalid rule.